# Terminal prompt changed after update

Tags: 13.04

I am newbie, using Ubuntu v 13.10 and after automatic update, when I started terminal

Instead of coming :

```
naveen@navyad$
```

it is coming like

```
~
```

(tilde in red color)

```
naveen@naveen-Lenovo-G580$
```

(in blue color)

on `ls` all directories coming blue colors (earlier white)

can someone help to sort it out.

**updated**
when directory is traversed like:

```
naveen@naveen-Lenovo-G580$ cd temp
```

is coming like

~/tmp
naveen@naveen-Lenovo-G580$

Comment: Normally directories are appeared as blue colour and files are appeared as white colour.

Comment: is that any `temp` folder in your home directory?

Comment: /home/naveen/tmp

Comment: Why do you need a `~/tmp` directory..? Is your user `root` or something...? :-s - user10607, Avinash won't know that you have answered, unless you do something like @AvinashRaj

Comment: i'm logged in as a root

Comment: That is probably why then, even though root's default 'home' directory should be `/home/root`. How are you logged in as root? `sudo -i`?

Comment: default diretocry is /home/naveen

Comment: Did you setup a user on install? It might be behaving like that because you didn't.

Comment: if you logged in as root it will be appears like `root@naveen-Lenovo-G580:~#`.

Comment: You don't need to login as root - just use `sudo` command.

Answer (score 0):

Terminal is sort of supposed to be like that.

You can change the colour it appears as in the <kbd>Edit</kbd> menu, look for <kbd>Profile Preferences</kbd>.

The `~` represents the directory you are currently in. The `~` means that it is in your home directory. If you change the the directory the terminal is in:

```
cd ~/Desktop
```

<sub>Change to directory `/home/USERNAME/Desktop`</sub>

You will get:

[image]

If you were then to run `ls`, you will get the contents of the `~/Desktop` folder, not including hidden files *(starting with `.`, and ending with `~`)*

The other bit is in the format:

```
USERNAME@HOSTNAME
```

As you can see above, my username is `wmobbs`, and the computer's hostname is `whm2`.

You can find what the computer's hostname is by running:

```
cat /etc/hostname
```

Which will give the contents of the `/etc/hostname` file.

```
wmobbs@whm2:~$ cat /etc/hostname 
whm2
wmobbs@whm2:~$
```

So the complete formula for it is:

```
USERNAME@HOSTNAME:/PATH/TO/DIRECTORY$
```

---

If you want to get dynamic colouring, like in the the above screenshot, change these lines:

```
# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=no
```

in the `~/.bashrc` file to:

```
# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
force_color_prompt=yes
```

You should be abke to get rid of it by changing it to `no`, or comment it out by adding a `#` at the beginning.

Comment: cd ~/Desktop not working, please check post update is been made

Comment: @AvinashRaj - ?